# Static HTML to PHP Navigation

Tags: php, html, dynamic, navigation

I'm looking to dynamically change the navigation of a static html site. I'd like to detect which page I'm on and adjusts the navigation accordingly, since certain pages are in folders and causing the navigation to break when linking back to previous pages. If I need to rebuild my navigation I'm okay with that. Just not sure how to deal with navigating nested folders in php.

**I have a site with a navigation structure like so**

```
index.php
sample-page.php
Resources(folder) > resource-1.php, resource-2.php, resource-3.php
Contact(folder) > contact-1.php, contact-2.php
```

I can go from index.php to Resources/resources-1.php fine but if I click resources-2.php I go to Resources/Resources/resources-1.php.

The same thing happens if I'm on Resources/resources-1.php to index.php I go to Resources/index.php instead of the root.

Not sure how to change this. I've broken up the nav so it's 
being inserted by `<?php include ("navigation.php"); ?>
  <?php set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ); ?>`

Thank you!

p.s. Sorry for the poor formatting, long time lurker and first time poster. Haven't quite figured out it out just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to include a forward slash to avoid the unwanted relative paths. Assuming / is your base:

```
<a href="/index.php">Index</a>
<a href="/sample-page.php">Sample Page</a>
<a href="/Resources/resource-1.php">Resources 1</a> 
<a href="/Resources/resource-2.php">Resources 2</a>
<a href="/Resources/resource-3.php">Resources 3</a>
<a href="/Contact/contact-1.php">Contact 1</a>
<a href="/Contact/contact-2.php">Contact 2</a>
```

Give that a go, I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Martin! This was very helpful and saved me hours of trying to figure this out. I'm using XAMPP so it actually took me too far, to the dashboard. But I added my enclosing folder for the entire site and then everything linked up perfectly. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: @user2966325 No problem, I'm glad it helped!